# RFduinoBLE library not working with OpenBCI_Radios library. Error while linking

Tags: c++, arduino, linker

I would like to know what about these libraries is causing this error when compiling in Arduino sketch:

```
c:/users/dmcar/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: address 0x200042c4 of C:\Users\DMCar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_482614/CytonRadio.ino.elf section `.bss' is not within region `ram'

c:/users/dmcar/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: address 0x200042c4 of C:\Users\DMCar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_482614/CytonRadio.ino.elf section `.bss' is not within region `ram'

c:/users/dmcar/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: address 0x200042c4 of C:\Users\DMCar\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_482614/CytonRadio.ino.elf section `.bss' is not within region `ram'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's my code

```
#include <RFduinoBLE.h>
#include <RFduinoGZLL.h>
#include "OpenBCI_Radios.h"

int blePin = 4;
bool isBle = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(blePin, INPUT);
  isBle = digitalRead(blePin);

  if (isBle) {
    // do ble setup
    RFduinoBLE.deviceName = "WEEGi";
    RFduinoBLE.advertisementInterval = 333;
    RFduinoBLE.txPowerLevel = -8;
    RFduinoBLE.advertisementData = "cyton";
    RFduinoBLE.begin();
  } else {
    // do gzll setup
    radio.begin(OPENBCI_MODE_DEVICE,20);
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

I know that the problem is caused by the usage of the RFduinoBLE library. I'm just not sure why. I have tried removing different sections of the code and the only thing that seems to get it to work is either commenting out the line `RFduinoBLE.begin();` or by removing the `radio.begin();` line and removing the `#include "OpenBCI_Radios.h"`.

So there is something going on between these two libraries causing something to fail while linking. I just can't seem to find what it is. Any suggestions are appreciated and here are the repos to look at source code:

- https://github.com/RFduino/RFduino
- https://github.com/OpenBCI/OpenBCI_Radios

Comment: I'm currently trying to setup RFDuinoBLE library aswell. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: No I was unable to resolve this issue.